# The window.open() can not overflow current window

Tags: javascript

```
window.open('','','width=1365,height=100,left=1365,top=0');
```

problem: The new window can not overflow current window........

Comment: You need to provide more detail if you want anyone to provide a sensible response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function to open popup windows with the same size of parent

```
function popup(url) 
{
 params  = 'width='+screen.width;
 params += ', height='+screen.height;
 params += ', top=0, left=0'
 params += ', fullscreen=yes';

 newwin=window.open(url,'windowname4', params);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}
```